# How can I make Visual Studio Code suggest tab-completions for any previous line in the file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

I want visual studio code to suggest an autocompletion for an entire line if I start typing the first few characters of any line already in the file, regardless of the content of the existing line. So if this is the content of my file:

```
this is a line with whitespace
this,is,a,comma,separated,list
```

And I type `this` on a new line, I would get a pop-up like any other autocomplete suggestion and I could fill in either of the lines above. How can I do this (and if I can't, is there another editor that has this ability)?

Comment: you can write an extension that has a `CompletionItemProvider`

Comment: I have written an extension for this: [Line Completion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.line-completion)

Comment: Amazing! If you post an answer I'll accept it when I have time to try out the extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension [Line Completion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.line-completion) does what you want.

You have to configure for which files (language identifiers) it should perform these suggestions. (To prevent to much calculation on large files where you don't use it. See the README page.

Comment: This is excellent! I only get suggestions for whole lines when I enable the extension - is it possible to have the normal word-based suggestions appear in the same list as the line completions?

Comment: @shortorian They should also appear, I sometimes have to type `Ctrl+Space` to see word suggestions

Comment: Ah, actually it turns out I was typing in a file that has way fewer words in it than I thought. Works perfectly.